# Google Video Intelligence API : inconsistent offset delta for Text Detection (and other features)

Tags: offset, video-intelligence-api

In `text_annotations` results, most bounding boxes have an offset that is a multiple of `0.12`. Lately we have found some offsets are now randomly multiples of `0.10` and, even worse, sometimes `0.01`.

Exemple:

```
time_offset {
      seconds: 10
      nanos: 110100000
    }
```

We also have tricky situations where rounding the value produces an outlying offset, here for example giving us `9.81` instead of the `9.80` we would need to stay consistent with the `0.10` deltas:

```
time_offset {
      seconds: 9
      nanos: 809800000
    }
```

Could someone clarify the rules for the offsets as we are debugging blind trying to take into account all these cases.

What time deltas do we need to cater for and what features use what deltas ?